# What is Foursquare API date format?

Tags: javascript, api, date, foursquare, date-format

I want to get photos of a Foursquare venue with the date when they were taken.
Here is an example of Foursquare API response :
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/43695300f964a5208c291fe3/photos 
The createdAt key has a strange date value like 1338472210 or 1318094639.

How to extract the date from these values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a unix timestamp if you pass it to the Date constructor it should parse it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var date = new Date(1338472210);    
var curr_date = date.getDate();
var curr_month = date.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = date.getFullYear();
document.write(curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

They are in "epoch" time: Unix epoch is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT), not counting leap seconds

```
var myDate = new Date( your epoch date *** 1000**);
document.write(myDate.toGMTString()+"<br>"+myDate.toLocaleString());
```

From http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/#javascript